# My css file is not working with the xmlworkloader

Tags: c#, css, itext, xmlworker

I am trying to print a pdf with external css file but my file reads from xml perfectly but does not apply the css to the pdf.

I have tried to do this code :

```
pdfDoc.Open();

string css = "D:\\Office\\cases_converter_tool\\cases_converter_tool\\styleCase.css ";
var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
cssResolver.AddCss(css, "utf-8", true);

//var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);

XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pdfWriter, pdfDoc, new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Dip\\Desktop\\MLRA_1982_402.xml")

PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, msReport);
pdfWriter.PageEvent = new ITextEvents();

pdfDoc.Open();
string css = "D:\\Office\\cases_converter_tool\\cases_converter_tool\\styleCase.css ";
var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
cssResolver.AddCss(css, "utf-8", true);

XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pdfWriter, pdfDoc, new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Dip\\Desktop\\MLRA_1982_402.xml"));
```

I expect the xml data should not overlaps with my headings.It shall leave a certain gap in the beginning and the end of the page for headers and footers section.

Comment: In the last line: why don't you use cssResolver.ParseXhtml? You already have the instance in the cssResolver.

Comment: I tried to do : 
cssResolver.ParseXhtml but it show no method for cssResolver.

Comment: I am Sorry that was my mistake, the GetDefaultCssResolver returns an CssResolver and not the instance.

Comment: So,what should be the correct way to approach the problem ? i want to leave some space at the start and end for my headers and footers.

Comment: Please take a look at this post: [CSS styles not being applied to PDF with iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131992/css-styles-not-being-applied-to-pdf-with-itextsharp)
Maybe this helps out.